# I want to add multiple data in mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 user and I want to insert more than one language(and degree) to him. How can I do this with php?

My languagetype table(all languages inserted)

```
CREATE TABLE TLANGUAGETYPE (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    language VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

My language table connected with user table.

```
CREATE TABLE TLANGUAGE (
    languageID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userID INT NOT NULL,
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    degree FLOAT,

    PRIMARY KEY (languageID),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES TUSER(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES TLANGUAGETYPE(ID)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the languageId in user Table. You can create a mapping table which just contains the "USERID" and "LanguageID" columns.